# QGIS Python console in bottom dock

Tags: qgis, gui, qgis-python-console

For some time (can't state exaclty when, why or what I've done) I have a weird behavior of the python console. Persistantly, it opens in a floating window like this ...

[image]

... wich really annoys me.

I can move it to the bottom dock, no problem, and I expect it to stay there when starting a new QGIS session, but no way. It persists opening in as a floating window.

The only way to overcome this seems to delete the default profile, but then of course all my program setting are gone. Not the very best approach.

This is what it looks like in a "fresh" QGIS:

[image]

Since I could not find anything about this in the *Options - Advanced...* section, **why is this? Am I missing any settings or so? Some secret checkbox?**

I'm on QGIS 3.22.14 LTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a workaroud and not really a clear answer to the question, but for the meantime it solves my problem.

When moving the default profile to some temporary location, start QGIS with a fresh default profile and then move `qgis.ini` and `qgis-auth.db` from the old profile to the new one the Python console behaves like expected and most of the settings are preserved.

Not very satisfactory though, but helpful at the moment.